# Create CImg<uint8_t> from byte array?

Tags: c++, cimg, phash

I'm trying to modify a C++ library that has a function that creates a CImg instance from an image file, to use a byte array instead.  Is this possible?  I found one method that appears to allow it...

```
CImg  ( const t *const  values,  
  const unsigned int  size_x,  
  const unsigned int  size_y = 1,  
  const unsigned int  size_z = 1,  
  const unsigned int  size_c = 1,  
  const bool  is_shared = false  
)
```

...but since all I have is the byte array, I don't have the dimensions of the source image.

UPDATED TO ADDRESS COMMENTS
This is an attempt to make a modification to the pHash library, which uses the CImg class as defined here http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html

The byte array is populated through an http request for the source image.

Comment: How are we supposed to know? We have no clue what `CImg` is, or what the dimensions are supposed to be, or what library you're using.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to allow anyone to provide a correct answer. Assuming that you are using [this API](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#abb574a5b3a62aea66c25332051716be0), you have to know the dimensions. How did you create and populate the byte array?

Comment: @Random: Considering that you got the dimensions of the image and you have a 2D image matrix, may I ask that how did you manage to create a CImg instance from the file?

Comment: I know that's an old question but you spoke about patching pHash, did you manage to do what I suppose is allowing loading pictures from memory ? I am trying to do the same thing but CImg is not really helping...

Comment: No, I couldn't get anything to work.  I just had to write the byte array to a temp file, and work with it from there.

Answer (score 2):

If your byte array contains a copy of the entire image file (not just the bitmap portion), then you can read the dimensions from the header.

See [`BITMAPFILEHEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`BITMAPINFOHEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (of course, for other formats such as PNG or JPEG, you'll need the corresponding headers).

For example, this will let you view an image from the network or your application resource segment, without first writing it to disk.